# Change vertical slider to horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I am new to jquery and have a vertical menu to be worked upon.The submenus of the menu are too much in number so the menu gets too deep when opened; so I need to slide out the submenus left instead of down when clicked upon.
the jquery code for the vertical menu is as follows:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 $(".goo-collapsible > li > a").on("click", function(e){

if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

  // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
    $(".goo-collapsible li ul").slideUp(350);
    $(".goo-collapsible li a").removeClass("active");

    // open our new menu and add the open class
    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
    $(this).addClass("active");

}else if($(this).hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
  }
 });

});
```

I want to replace the slideUp() and slideDown() function with some other alternative without editting the other part of the code.
I would be too grateful to the supporters :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code. Tried to set correct CSS but still it have some bugs but functionality is there what you are looking for.

```js
$(".goo-collapsible > li > a").on("click", function(e){

if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

  // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
    //$(".goo-collapsible li ul").slideUp(350);
    $(".goo-collapsible li ul").hide();
    $(".goo-collapsible li a").removeClass("active");

    // open our new menu and add the open class
    //$(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
    $(this).next("ul").show().animate({"left":"140px"}, "slow");
    $(this).addClass("active");

}else if($(this).hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).removeClass("active");
    //$(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    $(this).next("ul").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow",function(){$(this).hide();});
  }
 });
```

```css
.goo-collapsible{
  width:120px;
  border: solid 1px black;
 
  }

.goo-collapsible > li {
     background:cyan;
  z-index:10;
  opacity:1;
  
}

.goo-collapsible > li > a {
    padding: 6px 9.5px;
}

ul, ol, li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  display:none;
  left:0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:5;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="goo-collapsible">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Main Category</a>
                
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="/SubCat1">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="/SubCat1">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="/SubCat1">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
     </ul>
              </li>
     <li>
     <a  href="javascript:void(0);">About us</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="/about/history/">History</a></li>
     <li><a href="/about/team/">The team</a></li>
     <li><a href="/about/address/">Our address</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts vijay....i tried replacin the slideUp an slideDown function but they are not workin on my hierarchy of pages...nyways thanks :)